# Dado un arreglo y un index intencambiar posiciones

Tags: python

Estoy intentando cambiar posiciones de un arreglo dado un índice como parámetro en una función.

Tengo un `input`

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6] , index = 2;
```

El output debe ser el siguiente

```
[2,1,4,3,6,5]
```

¿Cómo podría abordarlo? Había intentado una solución con `for`, pero nada.

Comment: No queda clara la relación entre el parámetro y el resultado buscado. ¿Qué pasa con `index=3`?

Comment: Pero que posiciones vas a cambiar? La que recibes como input con cual otra?

Comment: Necesito cambiar las posiciones de los números en el array tal que el 2 pase a donde esta el 1 el 4 al 3 , el índice debería decirme la posición de cambio. Y si paso 3 pues debería ser en la posición 3.

Comment: Lo recomendable es que coloques lo que has avanzado de código, aquí las preguntas estilo "háganme este ejercicio o tarea" no son bienvenidas. Te recomiendo revisar [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Has visto la cantidad de variables que te falta aclarar con respecto al planteo?, además, es una lista no un arreglo.
Voy a suponer que lo cambios no son sobre la lista original y también supondré el intercambio.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
index = 2

def intercambia(lista,indice):
    cambiada = []
    if len(lista) % indice != 0:
        return "no es posible"
```

Hastá acá use tu planteo, lo único que agregue una lista nueva que será la devuelta y en caso de que el largo de la lista no sea correcto de acuerdo al índice de intercambio que de un mensaje de imposibilidad.

```
else:
    for x in range(0,len(lista),indice):
        cambiada.extend(lista[x:indice][::-1])
        indice+=indice
return cambiada
```

en caso contrario recorremos la lista cada intervalo indicado por el índice, tomando una sublista e invirtiendola para agregarla a la lista nueva

```
print(intercambia(arr,index))
```

devuelve en caso índice 2:

```
[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

y en caso índice 3:

```
[3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4]
```

sino es eso, intenta ser más conciso en el planteo y las posibilidades, que por cierto también podrías haber puesto lo que intentaste.

Comment: Recuerda que las respuestas se hacen con base en el código que deja el OP en su pregunta. No se hacen tareas, para no mal acostumbrar a la gente a encontrar soluciones fáciles. No es la visión de la comunidad

Comment: @JeanGotopo me remito a un caso anterior, supuse que el usuario lo intentó. No vi tu mismo comentario en ese caso ni voto negativo.

Comment: solo hice el comentario. EL voto negativo lo daría a la pregunta no a la respuesta, no lo di.

Comment: Agradezco la ayuda, no quería que me hicieran tarea, solo ayuda, soy nuevo en python, gracias !